# AutoLayout Storyboard constraints - how to modify in code to use this modification across Orientation changes

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

I consider what is the best way to modify values of Storyboard NSLayoutConstraint IBOutlets in such a way to have this modification persist the orientation/size class changes.

I have defined in storyboard constraint with Installed properties turn on for some size classes ex. Regular/Compact, and turn off for other size classes like Compact/Regular.

I can modify value of this constraint from code through IBOutlet in viewDidAppear() but it works only until I rotate device. 
After device rotation constraint is uninstalled, than again reinstalled with old storyboard value (or if deactivated in code just reactivated again).

So I tried to add additional modification in traitCollactionDidChange() method. BUT it doesn't work, it is called before Stroyboard constraint values are set! So my modification is overwritten by value defined in Storyboard.

Then I tried viewDidLayoutSubviews() (UIViewController) or layoutSubviews() (UIView). In the case of simple view it seems to work, but it was not reliable if I added more views modifications then calculations hangs my appliaction on rotation.

So as the last resort I have added Timer.scheduledTimer() with 1 second delay to traitCollectionDidChange() it seems to work, but it also seems to be vary odd hack. What if storyboard sets constraint values after this one second, maybe apple changes something in next versions of Swift/iOS. Could I relay on such hack?

My code:

```
 override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)

        if UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .pad  {
            bottomConstraint.isActive = false
        } else if traitCollection.sizeClasses == (.regular, .compact) {
            iphoneLeadingSpacerProportionalWidth = leadingSpacerProportionalWidth.setMultiplier(multiplier: 0.1)
            iphoneTrailingSpacerProportionaWidth = trailingSpacerProportionalWidth.setMultiplier(multiplier: 0.1)
        }
    }

    private var iphoneLeadingSpacerProportionalWidth : NSLayoutConstraint? = nil
    private var iphoneTrailingSpacerProportionaWidth : NSLayoutConstraint? = nil

    override func traitCollectionDidChange(_ previousTraitCollection: UITraitCollection?) {
        super.traitCollectionDidChange(previousTraitCollection)

        if let leadingConstraint = iphoneLeadingSpacerProportionalWidth,
            let trailingConstraint = iphoneTrailingSpacerProportionaWidth {
            NSLayoutConstraint.deactivate([leadingConstraint, trailingConstraint])
        }

        Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1, repeats: false) { (timer) in
            if UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .pad  {
                self.bottomConstraint.isActive = false
            } else if self.traitCollection.sizeClasses == (.regular, .compact) {
                self.iphoneLeadingSpacerProportionalWidth = self.leadingSpacerProportionalWidth.setMultiplier(multiplier: 0.1)
                self.iphoneTrailingSpacerProportionaWidth = self.trailingSpacerProportionalWidth.setMultiplier(multiplier: 0.1)
            }
        }
    }
```

Important! This **setMultiplier()** uses some extension I have found, so do not pay attantion to it it works the same way if I will set **constraint.constant = toSomeValue**

Answer (score 1):

You can set the different values for different size classes in storyboard itself. See attached.

[image]

[image]

if you still want to update via code. You should use this to detect the orientation.

```
override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
    if UIDevice.current.orientation.isLandscape {
        print("Landscape")
    } else {
        print("Portrait")
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes I know I have this size classes. But I have overrden w: R, h: C for iPad Landscape. And this size class is used now both for iPad Landscape and IPhone Plus, XS Max, XR in Landscape. Layout fits well both cases, but for example on iPad I would like to have greater margins 20% left/right, nad iPhone 10%. At the other view I have StackViews with menu icons, and size of Container changes in Portrait and layout and I am calculating width/height constants based on size of this container view.

Comment: Do you think viewWillTransition(to size: CGSzie, with coordinator ..) method will be called after constraints are set? traitCollactionDidChange() is called also when screen rotates and size classes change, but constraint from storyboards are set later in the lifecycle. I need place where I can safely modify constraints without delaying this constraint modification code.